# Object in Object in Array in Object? How do I retrieve data?

Tags: php, arrays, object

How do I retrieve ID and Name inside of AB_ID?  I don't want to loop inside the foreach, because there will always be one result and it seems unnecessary. ( unless it's the only way).

This is PHP.

```
print_r($response); // gives data below.  truncated.
QueryResult Object
(
    [queryLocator] => 
    [done] => 1
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Account_Name] => business_name
                    [Account] => account_no
                    [AB] => 12344567
                    [AB_more] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 123445
                            [Name] => Test 3
                        )
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
foreach($response as $key => $val) {
    $name = $val->Account_Name; #returns business_name
    $account = $val->Account; #returns account_no
    $ab = $val->AB; #returns 12344567

    // nothing below seems to work
    $ab_id = $val->AB_more->Id
    $ab_id = $val->AB_more.Id
    $ab_id = $val->AB_more[0]->Id
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does $name and $account works or do you have problem on those as well? Can you var_dump($val->AB_more) ?

Comment: I updated, sorry.  the data above is the print_r of $response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No loops at all:

```
$response->records[0]->Account_Name;  # business_name
$response->records[0]->Account;       # account_no
$response->records[0]->AB;            # 12344567
$response->records[0]->AB_more->Id;   # 123445
$response->records[0]->AB_more->Name; # "Test 3"
```

One loop:

```
foreach( $response->records[0] as $result ) {
    echo $result->Account_Name;
    echo $result->Account;
    echo $result->AB;
    echo $result->AB_more->Id;
    echo $result->AB_more->Name;
}
```

Comment: I meant to say I didn't want an inner loop ( I need the outer one ).

Comment: Updated with your loop.

Answer (score 0):

[Turn StdClass Objects into Arrays](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)

[get_object_vars() on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

I would recommend using get_object_vars to turn that Std Class Object into an Array. Do this for both inner Objects. This way you can just call [records][Id], or [records][Name].

Just my two cents. Hope this helps!